# Segmentation fault when dynamically allocating array

Tags: c, dynamic-allocation

I am writing a function to dynamically allocate a string array from my dictionary file that will be accessed through command line arguments.  I keep getting segmentation fault 11 and cannot figure out why

```
int
allocateArray(int count)
    {
    int i;
    char **array;
    char **argv;
    char *fileName = argv[1];
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    count = countTokens(argv);
    array = malloc(sizeof(char *) * count);
    if (array == 0)
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
        }
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
        array[i] = malloc(count);
        }
    for (i = 0; i < count; i ++)
        {
        fscanf (fp,"%s", array[i]);
        }
    free(array);
    fclose(fp);
    return **array;
    }
```

Comment: In addition to Happy's answer, how does countTokens handle argv?

Comment: countTokens counts the # of strings/tokens in the dictionary file passed as a command line argument

Answer (score 1):

In `char *fileName = argv[1];`, you dereference `argv[1]`. However, it isn't pointing to a memory location you own because you haven't allocated any memory to it on the previous line `char **argv;`.

You seem to be having some misunderstanding as to the command line arguments (CLA). In `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, `argv` is a CLA (as you seem to be already aware of). However, when `main()` calls another function, the CLA doesn't *automatically* get passed to it.

As a result, in your `int allocateArray(int count)` function, the `argv` that you declared is just another local variable. You would need to explicitly pass the `argv` from `main()` to `allocateArray()`.

The same goes for the other pointer variables in your code. I would recommend that you read up on "Scope and Lifetime of Variables" from a standard book. (I don't mean this in a condescending way.)